# Upgrade process from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2000, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server 2000 database that I would like to upgrade to SQL Server 2012 (running on a different server).

I don't think there is a direct upgrade path, but if there is, what is it?

My current plan is:

1. Backup SQL Server 2000 database
2. Restore on server with SQL Server 2008 installed
3. Set compatibility level to `100` (SQL Server 2008 / SQL Server 2008 R2)
4. Backup database from SQL Server 2008 server
5. Restore on server with SQL Serevr 2012 installed
6. Set compatibility level to `110` (SQL Server 2012)

Am I doing unneeded steps?  Am I missing anything (like running utilities to identify usage of unsupported Transact-SQL)?

Comment: You'll still want to do things like update statistics, but otherwise your process seems right to me.

Comment: Doesn't have to be 2008/R2 -- 2005 is supported on 2012.

Answer (score 5):

No, as I see it, you didn't miss anything. I have upgraded one of my databases from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2012.

Another way is to upgrade the entire server – in this case you can use the upgrade wizard.

UPDATE: my upgrade process was successful, but be careful about [discontinued and deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707782%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) features in SQL Server 2008 and 2012.

Comment: Is there an automated way to identify those discontinued and depreciated features?

Comment: As for 2000->2008, this way is to use the Upgrade Wizard. In your SQL Server 2000 you should run SQL Server 2008 setup and then select Planning -> Install upgrade adwizor. After install try to run it. But I didn't tryed to do it on windows 2000, maybe this method will not work.

Comment: You can't upgrade directly from 2000 to 2012. You will need to first upgrade to 2005/2008/2008 R2, update the compatibility level of your databases to 90 or 100, and then upgrade to 2012.

Comment: @AaronBertrand is it a must to change the compatibility level for the upgrade process?

Comment: Yes because SQL Server 2012 does not support 80 (2000) compatibility. You don't *have* to change it all the way up to 110, but you should only keep it in 90 or 100 if you have a good reason...

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to columns containing blog posts, for example.

The `text`, `ntext` and `image` data types frequently used in SQL Server 2000, are [deprecated in SQL Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) (although they are still available), and should be replaced with `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)` and `varbinary(max)` data types, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick query to see if any of your tables are using deprecated data types.

```
SELECT  sys.objects.NAME AS [table_name] ,
        sys.columns.NAME AS [column_name] ,
        sys.types.NAME AS [data_type]
FROM    ( sys.columns
          INNER JOIN sys.objects ON sys.objects.object_id = sys.columns.object_id
        ) INNER JOIN sys.types ON sys.types.system_type_id = sys.columns.system_type_id
WHERE   sys.types.name IN ( 'text', 'ntext', 'image' )
```